# Drawing map with ggplot and draw dots in map

Tags: r, coordinates, r-sf

I work on a dataset with distilleries of Scotland and I want to visualize their locations on a map.
So I used the following code to draw Scotland and its surrounding like this:

```
library(SpatialEpi)
library(tmap)
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("rgeos")
library("ggspatial")
library("ggrepel")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-13.68, 0.72), ylim = c(54.63, 60.85), expand = FALSE)
```

Afterwards, I used the Longitude/Latitude-information of the dataset whisky and tried to draw the distilleries as points (the dataset can be downloaded here: [whisky](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbusvjulh5yw8a5/whisky_data.csv?dl=0)):

```
whisky <- read.csv("whisky_data.csv")
mapdata <- whisky[,c(1,15:16)]
mapdata$Latitude <- as.numeric(mapdata$Latitude)
mapdata$Longitude <- as.numeric(mapdata$Longitude)

coordinates(mapdata)<-~Longitude+Latitude
class(mapdata)

# does it have a projection/coordinate system assigned?
proj4string(mapdata)  # Nope

# check coordinate system of world
st_crs(world)  # +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84

# manually tell R what the coordinate system is
proj4string(mapdata)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-13.68, 0.72), ylim = c(54.63, 60.85), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data=as.data.frame(mapdata), aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="red")
```

But there are no points shown in the map.
I guess I didn't transform the coordinates correctly to be drawn into the world map?

As I'm an absolute beginner in mapping I'm grateful for any help with this!!
Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case is a strong one / whisky, what a lovely word?

Consider this code; it is built on the {sf} package and the `ggplot2::geom_sf()` function. For more information do have a look at this post on the RStudio forum discussing other options for drawing a map https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-packages-for-making-map-leaflet-vs-ggmap-vs-sf-vs/38403/2?u=jlacko

But one way or the other, this code should get you started.

```
library(sf) # general spatial manipulation
library(giscoR) # for the shape of Scotland
library(dplyr) # general data frame manipulation
library(ggplot2) # because ggplot...

# Scotland as a spatial object
scotland <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(nuts_id = 'UKM',
                                   resolution = '01') 

# yer data
distilleries <- read.csv("whisky_data.csv") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Latitude", "Longitude"), crs = 4326)

# a quick reality check - looks legit
mapview::mapView(distilleries)

# a ggplot object
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = scotland, fill = NA, color = "gray45") + # borders of Scotland
  geom_sf(data = distilleries, pch = 4, color = "red") + # the distilleries
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Distilleries of Scotland") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1/2))
```

[image: distilleries of Scotland map]

Comment: Hi Jindra. I found your comment really helpful for a problem I was facing. I would like to ask you something else: do you know if there is any way to represent in the map, instead of the red crosses, a label? For example, imagine that there are 5 distilleries in the same location: would it be possible, in such location, represent the number 5?

Comment: Hi Jesús, yes it is possible - but in this context (static ggplot2 map) not quite straightforward. A lot hinges on "the same location" part - is 1 meter difference enough to call it "the same"? or rather 10 kilometers? It really is a separate question, answering which does not fit a simple comment / but should you raise one, wink wink, I will share some code. Or you can have a look at leaflet, it has a helpsul `clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()` / https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html#marker-clusters setting for clusters.